# Openpyxl throws an error while loading workbook

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, export-to-excel

I've an excel file that is generated by exporting a data table to excel. that excel file has data errors(yellow icon on cell) like "The number is this cell is formated as text".

When i try to load that excel file using openpyxl

```
openpyxl.load_workbook("workbook")
```

this line throws below exception

```
    C:\Users\rgfadmin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe     C:/Users/rgfadmin/Desktop/Automation/AutoTransactionLoad/Validation.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 57, in _convert
    value = expected_type(value)
TypeError: 'datetime.date' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File     "C:\Users\rgfadmin\Desktop\Automation\AutoTransactionLoad\Validation.py", line 11, in <module>
    error_book = xl.load_workbook(error_path)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 319, in load_workbook
    reader.read()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 278, in read
    self.read_properties()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 175, in read_properties
    self.wb.properties = DocumentProperties.from_tree(src)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 104, in from_tree
    return cls(**attrib)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\packaging\core.py", line 110, in __init__
    self.modified = modified
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 270, in __set__
    super(DateTime, self).__set__(instance, value)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\nested.py", line 36, in __set__
    super(Nested, self).__set__(instance, value)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 69, in __set__
    value = _convert(self.expected_type, value)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 59, in _convert
    raise TypeError('expected ' + str(expected_type))
TypeError: expected <class 'datetime.datetime'>

Process finished with exit code 1
```

[image]
If I convert all those error cells to "convert to number" in excel manually the code starts working perfectly. how can I fix the cell error as it's an auto-generated excel file and I can't fix it manually?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: A sample of the data might help.

Comment: I've added the pics to explain it better.